# Resque vs. Sidekiq

Tags: ruby, resque, job-queue, sidekiq

I'm working on a project with a friend where we've been using Resque for processing various commands from data input inside our rails application on a minute to minute basis.

We've been messing around with the idea of using Sidekiq because it is multi-threaded and won't be a memory hog and won't need to boot a ruby env for each worker.

I'm hoping to gather some thoughts and opinions from people that use Resque and Sidekiq in real time and explain the differences.

So, what are the pros and cons of Sidekiq against Resque?

Comment: Updated tags for better relevance and to note that this isn't a rails-specific concern.

Comment: I also think the question could use some work so it doesn't attract "subjective" answers. Without editing, this question may get closed as I've seen happen many times.

Comment: While no one want's to answer a subjective question, I will - Sidekiq for the win, especially if you need high performance and memory efficiency. There is nothing "harder" or more "complicated" about using sidekiq, except for having thread safe code (if you use multiple threads in sidekiq), and thats a very very small concern for most well-written object oriented code (avoid class variables). https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testimonials